# How to request similar to HTTPPost on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, http-post

In my application, on clicking a link, I need to open a new tab with result page of HTTP Post.

For example, I'm on website abc.com. There is a link on this page for URL xyz.com/somepage. somepage has a form with a search box. The form is of method POST. Is there way I can submit this form from abc.com on click of a URL ?

On server side, I know we can do this using HTTP Post. Is there similar solution on client side ?

Answer (score 0):

So you're asking a few different things:

1) can I submit a POST request when a user clicks a link -- yes (javascript)
2) can I have that submit open in a new tab -- yes, target="_blank" on the form
2) can I submit a Cross-Domain post request using javascript -- maybe... probably not.

1) For forms on the same page as the javascript, you can simply find the element (by name, id, class name, etc) and then submit() it.  That will act just like the user clicked the form submit button.

2) To have it open in a new tab, the  tag would have to have target="_blank" set also.  i.e.

`<form target="_blank" action="hteeteepee://xyz.com/somepage" method="POST">`

3) If you want, on abc.com you can have the form exist and have the action set to the receiving script on xyz.com.  You may run into origin issues, however, depending on how the script on xyz.com is setup.

Comment: "can I submit a Cross-Domain post request using javascript -- maybe... probably not." this is what I want to do

Comment: So write your javascript to submit the form, inject it onto a page that has the form, and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this method. But you can try.

When you click on a link in abc.com, store your parameters to be submitted as post in xyz.com in some cookie variable. When user clicks your link, open a new tab, with abc.com/search or some other url in your domain itself. In that url, you should load xyz.com as iframe. And using javascript take the params to be submitted from the cookie variable and submit the form. So the user stays with you and gets what he want.